# AJAX response data not displaying in table td

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom, innerhtml

I have a HTML table with structure below:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:view_note('<?php echo $id; ?>')">View note</a>
    </td>
<tr>     
<tr>
    <td id="abcd" >
        <span id="hidtb_<?php echo $applicants_r[$i]['id']; ?>"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My javascript is :

```
function view_note(id)
{
    document.getElementById('abcd').style.display="block";
    ---------------
    --------------
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDiv = document.getElementById('hidtb_'+id);
            //alert('hidtb_'+id);
            ajaxDiv.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }

    var queryString = "?id=" + id;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "view_note.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

But when I click on view note,though it shows the `td` `abcd`,it displays nothing ! But when I alert the `alert(ajaxRequest.responseText)` , it alerts desired result. Whats wrong?

Comment: Check your browser's console for errors. Also, check the `ID`s for both elements (`a` and `span`) in your `HTML`.

Comment: Are you sure that `$id` and `$applicants_r[$i]['id']` give the same value?

Comment: `document.getElementById('abcd').style.display` should be `table-cell` instead of `block`

Comment: in your html, line no 5, shouldn't it be `</tr>` instead of `<tr>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the `<tr id="abcd">` that is causing errors since it is set to `display:none` in the css. Try this:

```
<tr id="abcd_<?php echo  $applicants_r[$i]['id']; ?>" style="display: none">
    <td>
        <span id="hidtb_<?php echo  $applicants_r[$i]['id']; ?>"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript/Ajax:

Change

`document.getElementById('abcd').style.display="block";`

To
`document.getElementById('abcd_'+id).style.display="block";`